# Como fazer join com mais de duas listas?

Tags: c#, linq

Tenho três classes:

```
class Cbo
{
    public string ProfId { get; set; }
    public string Cbo { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
}

class Profissional
{
    public string ProfId { get; set; }
    public string NomeProf { get; set; }
}

class Vinculo
{
    public string UnidadeId { get; set; }
    public string ProfId { get; set; }
    public string Cbo { get; set; }
    public string NomeProf { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
}
```

Preciso criar uma lista usando LINQ:

```
select * from Cbo, Profissional, Vinculo where
Cbo.ProfId = Profissional.ProfId and
Vinculo.ProfId = Profissional.ProfId
```

Sei fazer com duas tabelas assim:

```
List<Vinculo> result = (from vinculo in listaVinculo join profissional in listaProfissional on vinculo.ProfId equals profissional.ProfId
select new Vinculo()
{
Cbo = vinculo.Cbo,
NomeProf = profissional.NomeProf,
ProfId = profissional.ProfId,
UnidadeId = vinculo.UnidadeId
}).ToList();
```

Com esse código eu uno as classes `Profissional` e `Vinculo`, mas ainda não sei como incluir a classe `Cbo` para pegar o campo `descricao`.

Comment: Esta usando ORM?

Comment: oi, sou novato em C# e não sei informar se estou usando ORM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O Linq possui o comando `join` que permite juntas as tabelas ou listas de acordo com um critério estabelecido, neste caso o critério usado são os IDs das suas listas `Cbo`, `Profissional` e `Vinculo`.

Usei o `ProfId` de relação, mas pode ser usados outros.

Veja este exemplo:

```
var joinRes = (
                from Item1 in profs
                join Item2 in cbos on Item1.ProfId equals Item2.ProfId
                join Item3 in vins on Item2.ProfId equals Item3.ProfId
                select new
                {
                    Item1,
                    Item2,
                    Item3
                }
              ).ToList();

joinRes.ForEach(x => 
{
    Console.WriteLine(x.Item1.NomeProf);
    Console.WriteLine(x.Item2.Descricao);
    Console.WriteLine(x.Item3.Descricao);
});
```

Saída

> Gato
>   Aqui e a descricao do Cbo
>   Unidade do Gato

Segue o código completo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace JoinExemploLinq
{
    class Cbo
    {
        public string ProfId { get; set; }
        public string CboId { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
    }

    class Profissional
    {
        public string ProfId { get; set; }
        public string NomeProf { get; set; }
    }

    class Vinculo
    {
        public string UnidadeId { get; set; }
        public string ProfId { get; set; }
        public string CboID { get; set; }
        public string NomeProf { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Cbo> cbos = new List<Cbo>
            {
                new Cbo
                {
                    ProfId = "1",
                    CboId = "1",
                    Descricao = "Aqui e a descricao do Cbo"
                }
            };

            List<Profissional> profs = new List<Profissional>
            {
                new Profissional
                {
                    ProfId = "1",
                    NomeProf = "Gato"
                }
            };

            List<Vinculo> vins = new List<Vinculo>
            {
                new Vinculo
                {
                    UnidadeId = "1",
                    ProfId = "1",
                    CboID = "1",
                    NomeProf = "Gato",
                    Descricao = "Unidade do gato"
                }
            };

            var joinRes = (
                            from Item1 in profs
                            join Item2 in cbos on Item1.ProfId equals Item2.ProfId
                            join Item3 in vins on Item2.ProfId equals Item3.ProfId
                            select new
                            {
                                Item1,
                                Item2,
                                Item3
                            }
                          ).ToList();

            joinRes.ForEach(x => 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x.Item1.NomeProf);
                Console.WriteLine(x.Item2.Descricao);
                Console.WriteLine(x.Item3.Descricao);
            });

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

[Vale a pena a leitura](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb397906.aspx).

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723985/linq-join-2-listts).